# Flutter Conditional Route with Auto Route not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

i want to implement conditional routing with auto route package
isLoggedIn returns true but
autoroute redirects to login page,
how can i resolve this problem

```dart
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:bot_toast/bot_toast.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:expense/config/routes/app_router.dart';
import 'package:expense/config/themes/theme_config.dart';
import 'package:expense/constants/assets_path_constants.dart';
import 'package:expense/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:expense/core/auth/login/bloc/cubit/auth_cubit.dart';
import 'package:expense/core/auth/login/repository/mongodb/mongo_auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:expense/utils/services/lang/language_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'core/splash_screen.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  statusBar();
  await _init();
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: LanguageService.instance.supportedLocales,
      path: AssetsPath.langAssetPath,
      child: const Expense(),
    ),
  );
}

void statusBar() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarColor: ColorConstants.backgroundColor,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> _init() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
}

class Expense extends StatefulWidget {
  const Expense({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Expense> createState() => _ExpenseState();
}

class _ExpenseState extends State<Expense> {
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();
  bool isLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthCubit(MongoAuthRepository()),
      child: BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          context.read<AuthCubit>().isValid(); 
          return _buildMaterialApp(context, state);
        },
        listener: (context, state) {
           if (state is TokenIsValid) {
            isLoggedIn = state.isValid;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  MaterialApp _buildMaterialApp(BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
    print(isLoggedIn);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Gider',
      // Tost Mesajı Init
      builder: BotToastInit(),
      theme: CustomTheme.primaryTheme,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: const SplashPage(),
        animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        nextScreen: MaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: CustomTheme.primaryTheme,
          routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(includePrefixMatches: true),
          routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(
            initialRoutes: [
              if (isLoggedIn) HomeRoute(response: null) else const LoginRoute(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you fetch isloggedin? From shared pref?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of Code-image, more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i use bloc cubit, i shared code below @KaushikChandru

Comment: i included @YeasinSheikh